# How to find all occurences of an email address on a website

Tags: email

Let's say I have a large website which may have a number of email addresses on it that are getting picked up by spammers.  I plan to obfuscate or remove them all.

What's the easiest way to crawl my website to find any email addresses I may be exposing?

Either through on-page text (which Google can pick up, but not very well) or mailto: links (which Google can't).

Comment: What kind of website content? Static HTML, dynamic?

Comment: The same way that spammers do.

Comment: Sorry LukeR didn't see your question.  I was looking for a solution that wasn't dependant on server-side technology - so would work with static, dynamic etc equally.  The site in question uses a combination of static site plus blog software plus other software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
wget --mirror --html-extension http://www.mydomain.org/ -o /home/user/temp_site/
```

then

```
grep -Hinr "@mydomain.org" /home/user/temp_site/ > /home/user/list_of_pages_with_email
```

Should return a list of all pages (with line numbers) that contain your domains email addresses.

Might need tweaking.

Manuals for [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) and [grep](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)

Comment: Ah, I'd forgotten about wget's --mirror option.  Thanks!